# How to find the root class with N'ary inherited classes in PHP

Tags: php, class

When accessing parent functions in classes I find my self doing this

$this->parent->parent->parent->my_function()

Is it possible with one function to climb up a tree of classes to get to the first main object?

I have provided an example class structure to show a few classes inheriting others.

```
<?php
class a {

   public $b_classes;

   public function __construct()
   {
      echo 'In '. __CLASS__ .' Constructor<br>';
      $this->print_time();
      $this->b_classes[] = new b($this);
   }
   public function print_time() {
     print time() . "<br>";
   }
}

class b {
  public $c_classes, $d_classes;
  public $parent;

   public function __construct($parent)
   {
      $this->parent = $parent;
      echo 'In '. __CLASS__ .' Constructor<br>';
      $this->parent->print_time();
      $this->c_classes[] = new c($this);
      //$this->d_classes[] = new d($this);

   }
}

class c  {

  public $parent;

  public function __construct($parent)
  {
     $this->parent = $parent;
     echo 'In '. __CLASS__ .' Constructor<br>';
     $this->parent->parent->print_time();
  }
}

class d extends c {
  public $parent;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->parent = $parent;
     echo 'In '. __CLASS__ .' Constructor<br>';
  }
}






$x = new a();


echo "<pre>";

print_r($x);
echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Your classes presumably inherit from their parents, so `$this->my_function()` should work fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: Re: your edit, this is some really weird code. What are you trying to accomplish with it? Have you considered something like dependency injection?

Comment: I want to create a relationship of classes that can understand their parents.  So for example, a car can have 4 wheels and each wheel can have 8 lug nuts.  If i destroy the car, all the wheels and lug nuts can get destroyed.  But the idea of the lugnut to understand the properties of the car is critical.  I am not familiar with dependency injection, looking that up now...

Comment: A lugnut's parent isn't the wheel, or the car. It may be *attached* to them, but that's very different. A lugnut's parent class would be something like a *fastener*. A car or wheel would keep track of its lugnuts; the lugnuts don't care about the car.